# XML file keeps being overwritten

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, webforms

So I'm currently working on an ASP.NET project. It requires me to write a List<> onto a XML file. I created a "data.xml" file within the project folder and here are my few lines of code:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<BookItem>));
TextWriter filestream = new StreamWriter("data.xml");
serializer.Serialize(filestream, book);
filestream.Close();
```

it works well
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Nrqh.png)
  until I want to add a new record, then the file is overwritten every single time. I believe i only need few tricky lines of code to solve this problem but since my research didn't bring up any answer, i really need your help.

Comment: Can you show how you're adding the new record, and then how you're updating the file? Code snippets are OK, but we need the whole picture to help.

Comment: You are indeed rewriting the file, and also, a serialized class with XML can't just be appended, you must deserialize the saved content, add the new content to the list and then serialize it again replacing the file's content.

Comment: That's all i have about the xml file. So i believe that i approached the problem in a total wrong way :-?

Comment: You're doing it pretty much right. It's normal for the file to be overwritten each time you do this. Do you maybe mean something slightly different from what you're asking? Why is it a problem that the file gets overwritten? Are you losing data?

Comment: Perhaps you are only serializing a single `book` as indicated by the variable name, and not the list of books?

Comment: The code is fine.  It must be the way you are adding items to book that is wrong.  Book only has one list item.